# Unable to start Grizzly http server

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, grizzly

I am getting below error when I try starting Grizzly server from Java code. Please help.

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Failed to start Grizzly HTTP server: Cannot assign requested address: bind
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:299)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:119)
>       at org.alm.TestClient.setUp(TestClient.java:40)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:525)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:202)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:130)
>       at 
> org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:173)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1178)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:757)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:608)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1158)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1083)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:999)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
>   Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
>       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)

Code

```
@BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig(AlmApiStub.class);
        System.out.println(config.host()+config.port());
        server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                URI.create(String.format("https://%s:%s/", config.host(), config.port())), rc);
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println(config.host()+config.port());` can you share the output ?

Comment: qualitycenter.internal.xxx.com8443

Answer (score 2):

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Failed to start Grizzly HTTP server:
>   ***Cannot assign requested address: bind*** at

Make sure, there aren't any application running on same machine, using same port i.e. `8443`. Because Grizzly would be trying to acquire same port, but it might be held-up by another application on same machine. Alternatively, you could try assigning different port.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have checked if 8443 is in use or not but i dont see it used anywhere in my local machine.. Any other issue you see here?

Comment: @dileepvarma you aren't doing anything special. It is something related to network/ip/port.

Comment: I got you.But Its the Server side application and I cannot be able to change the port. I tried changing multiple ports in the code but for all open ports I used its giving the same error

Comment: @dileepvarma probably, you could try using ip address and try other combinations of port. Also, how are you so sure that these ports are not being used ?

Comment: @dileepvarma this you are running on server machine i.e ` 
qualitycenter.internal.xxx.com`

Comment: I tried localhost:10000 now im able to go through this step. Do you think URI.create is causing this?

Comment: Im not creating any connection here. im just using existing API server url to connect to ALM. Im not sure why it is saying port is in use at server side

Comment: @dileepvarma I don't think so, but AFAIK, it was mostly related to port issue

Comment: @dileepvarma You need to understand this, if you are creating any connection, then you are going to use server config where server is currently running. But, if you are going to start any server/application. which is your case, application will try to acquire specific port. If port is not available, then it will fail

Comment: @dileepvarma If your problem was resolved then you should upvote and accept the answer to make it helpful for other. This is what community expects. Please read here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235. You are not new here, and it wasn't expected from you to hold a post open for longer.

Comment: @dileepvarma You should understand how people put their effort and time to answer any post. You should always try conclude the post by accepting the answer or clarify the actual question. So, that other should get benefited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i have upvoted as yours is valid point. but this doesnt solve my issue. Thanks

Comment: @dileepvarma so, you are saying your problem was unresolved ?

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this error but for a different reason:  DNS.

TLDR:  verify your host maps to your machine.

I configured my service to run using www.sample.com [use your hostname] but it was mapped to a different machine's IP address. While I had mapped it in the host file it wasn't being honored.  That is a mystery for a different day.  When I changed the hostname to *test*.sample.com and verified it mapped to localhost I was able to bind to the address:port I wanted.